# rich.table Returning Incorrect Number of Results

Tags: python, web-scraping, rich

I'm scraping movie information by year. When I try print statement it prints all 100 movies, but when I use rich.table print I get only first movie.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from rich.table import Table
from rich.console import Console

table = Table()

url = 'https://www.rottentomatoes.com/top/bestofrt/?year='

year = input('Top 100 Movies for Which Year? ')
response = requests.get(url + year)
html = response.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
containers = soup.find_all('table', class_='table')

for container in containers:
    for row in container.find_all('tr')[1:]:
        movie_rank = row.find('td', class_='bold')
        movie_rank = movie_rank.text

        movie_name = row.find('a', class_='unstyled articleLink')
        movie_name = movie_name.text.strip()
        movie_name = movie_name.strip('(' + year + ')')

        movie_rating = row.find('span', class_='tMeterScore')
        movie_rating = movie_rating.text

        # print(f'{movie_rank} {movie_name.strip()} - rating:{movie_rating}')
        table.add_column('Rank')
        table.add_column('Movie')
        table.add_column('Rating')
        # problem is here     
        table.add_row(movie_rank, movie_name, movie_rating)
       
        console = Console()
        console.print(table)
        break
```

Comment: The problem is not where you said it is.  Those last three lines should be shifted two tabs to the left, so they are not part of the loops.  Right now, you do one row in one container, then you print the results and exit the loop.  Shift those three lines to line up with the `for container in containers:` line.

Comment: You have a `break` immediately after `console.print(table)` --- that ends your loop after one movie.

Comment: thank you, but still not working.. I did exactly as u said shifted the last three lines to line up with the for loop.

Comment: elliott, I tried it before but it's the same result...

Comment: You tried what before? Remove the `break`. That terminates your loop immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You terminate your loop immediately after one iteration of your loop, you should print the table once after you construct it. Also, you should add the columns once (not per iteration). Like,

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from rich.table import Table
from rich.console import Console

table = Table()
table.add_column('Rank')
table.add_column('Movie')
table.add_column('Rating')

url = 'https://www.rottentomatoes.com/top/bestofrt/?year='

year = input('Top 100 Movies for Which Year? ')
response = requests.get(url + year)
html = response.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
containers = soup.find_all('table', class_='table')

for container in containers:
    for row in container.find_all('tr')[1:]:
        movie_rank = row.find('td', class_='bold')
        movie_rank = movie_rank.text

        movie_name = row.find('a', class_='unstyled articleLink')
        movie_name = movie_name.text.strip()
        movie_name = movie_name.strip('(' + year + ')')

        movie_rating = row.find('span', class_='tMeterScore')
        movie_rating = movie_rating.text

        table.add_row(movie_rank, movie_name, movie_rating)

console = Console()
console.print(table)
```